# Key Value Coding for `description` property - Is this completely idiotic?

Tags: objective-c, kvc

I am jumping into a codebase that I'm unfamiliar with to resolve a critical crash, so I'm interested in finding a quick fix for the problem below that I can patch and come back to refactor later.

There is a strong coupling between the JSON structure returned by the web service and the Objective-C domain objects. The problem is that the JSON has a key `description` which is already declared as part of the `NSObject` protocol.

JSON:

```
{
    "channel" : {
        "description" : "blah",
        "mount"       : "blah",
        "status"      : "blah"
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface ABCChannel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *mount;
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *status;

@end
```

Not surprising, the parsing code uses KVC to shuttle values from JSON to ObjC instances. From what I can tell, for Swift interop Apple has changed the internals of `NSObject`'s `description` from a method to a `readonly` property. Clang emits this:

> warning: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'description' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property [-Wobjc-property-synthesis]

Okay. So ,I see two options:

1. (Preferred) Change the name of the property from `description` to something else. The problem is the parser will throw an exception in `setValue:forKey:` because of the undefined `description` key.
2. Back the `description` property with an instance variable using `@synthesize description = _channelDescription;`

---

I see option #1 as taking a step in the direction of the inevitable future refactor, and I would like to set myself up for that, if possible. I can fix the KVC problem with `ABCChannel` class no longer being compliant for the `description` key with the following code:

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        return [self valueForKey:@"details"];
    }

    return [super valueForUndefinedKey:key];
}

- (void)setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [self setValue:value forKey:@"details"];
    }
    else {
        [super setValue:value forUndefinedKey:key];
    }
}
```

**I am wondering if this is a terrible idea that will cause problems, and if I should just back the `description` property with an ivar and completely address the refactor later.**

Comment: It seems to me that the job of translating from the JSON keys to the model property names is logic that belongs in the parser, not the model. So, just put a special case in the parser that, when it's about to use KVC to set the model property from the JSON, checks if the key is "description" and, if so, alters the property name it's going to use.

Comment: @KenThomases I *completely* agree, however those that came before me did not think that way. Crawling through the parsing code and refactoring it is at the top of my todo once I get this other critical bug fix out the door.

Comment: `-valueForUndefinedKey:` will never be called with the key "description" because there is a getter for that property. So, the best you could do with that approach would be asymmetric, which strikes me as a bad idea. You could override `-valueForKey:` and `-setValue:forKey:` to translate the key before calling through to super, but that prevents anything from actually accessing the `NSObject` description using KVC (although that's probably uncommon). My experience is that overriding the description property is risky because it gets called for logging, etc. (although I guess that's status quo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backing the `description` property with an instance variable was the safest bet, especially for consistency across iOS 7 and iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the dictionary from the JSON parser through a function that returns a copy of the dictionary with "description" as a key universally changed to something sane.  Then rename the property in the code.

Would probably be fast to change this way too